# Error 'Undefined reference to' while compiling a project in Eclipse\C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I'm a beginner in C++. I've a project called `myProject` and an header file given to me, called `myLIB.h` with a method

```
int connect(char *);
```

I moved the header in my Project and included in my main file like this

```
#include "myLIB.h"
```

My problem is when I start to type `connect`, Eclipse IDE suggests me the method in myLIB.h

```
int fd = connect(devName);
```

but, when I try to build and compile, I get the following error:

```
 Undefined reference to connect( char *)
```

I can't understand where the problem is. The .h is included, Eclipse sees the methods but at building time, I get always this error.

Comment: I believe this is a **link error**. The compiler finds the prototype `int connect(char*)` in the header. Thus, it "knows" that there is an implementation though it's not in the "seen" source code. The corresponding library (with implementation) is probably separately or pre-compiled and must be linked to the executable. If the linker is not able to find any object file or library with an implementation of `connect` it reports "Undefined reference".

Comment: There is a more detailed explanation of compiler and linker in [SO: How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264256/7478597).